# Python best practices: data models

Tags: python, database

I am currently working on several Python packages that involve data processing, storage and a web interface.

In order to link the stored data (in databases) to the web interface, I am currently using classes representing the data used through all these packages. These classes contain therefore methods to load and transform raw data from database, to transform back and save in the database along with processing methods specific to the type of concept the data is representing.

I would like to explode these classes to have a more segregated approach. For example, on one hand, data model classes with the raw data contained in database and on the other hand classes based on the raw data (instances of data model classes) to perform thematic work.

In order to illustrate my situation, let's consider a database containing a table "localized_event" where fields are:
 - a date (as an unix timetag, integer)
 - a latitude (as a floating point value)
 - a longitude (as a floating point value)

What I have now is one single class with ability to load from raw data (*from_dict* method), generate SQL to save (*sql_insert* method) but still offers the user evolved attributes (*datetime*, etc.):

```
from dummy_geo_module import LatLon

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

...

class LocalizedEvent(object):

    def __init__(self, date_event, latitude, longitude):

        if isinstance(self.start_validity, int):
            self.date_event = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(seconds=timestamp)
        else:
            self.date_event = date_event

        self.geo_coord = LatLon(latitude, longitude)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dict):
        return cls(None if 'date_event' not in dict.keys() else dict['date_event'],
                   None if 'latitude' not in dict.keys() else dict['latitude'],
                   None if 'longitude' not in dict.keys() else dict['longitude'])

    def sql_insert(self, table):
        query = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ' + table + ' ' + '(date_event, latitude, longitude) VALUES ?, ?, ?'
        return query, self.get_table_tuple()

    def get_table_tuple(self):
        return (int((self.date_event - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)),
            self.geo_coord.lat, 
                self.geo_coord.lon,)

    ...
```

It would seem good to split this class, (i) a data model class to interact with the database:

```
class LocalizedEventData(object):

    def __init__(self, date_event, latitude, longitude):

        self.date_event = date_event
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dict):
        return cls(None if 'date_event' not in dict.keys() else dict['date_event'],
                   None if 'latitude' not in dict.keys() else dict['latitude'],
                   None if 'longitude' not in dict.keys() else dict['longitude'])

    def sql_insert(self, table):
        query = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ' + table + ' ' + '(date_event, latitude, longitude) VALUES ?, ?, ?'
        return query, (self.date_event, self.latitude, self.longitude)

    ...
```

and (ii) a class to be used in processing (using the evolved attribute and any kind of methods), etc.

```
from dummy_geo_module import LatLon

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

...

class LocalizedEvent(object):

    def __init__(self, locevt_data):

        self.date_event = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(seconds=locevt_data.timetag_event)
        self.geo_coord = LatLon(locevt_data.latitude, locevt_data.longitude)

    ...
```

Any suggestions about best practises for this kind of design ?

Comment: Or you could use SQLAlchemy which basically forces you into what you're trying to do anyway

Comment: I thought about it for the data models (or Django). But is it common practice to define another class to work with the data ?

Comment: Django is a web framework, but you could use it. You're asking if ORM or DAO objects are a common pattern? I think so, but it's simply a layer of redirection and some people don't like it for a performance reasons